# Visual studio 2010 Forms design error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dotnetbar

I am using `DotNetBar` in my application which I have developed in VS 2010.

I have removed the `DotNetBar` once and open the form which is using the `DotNetBar` component, but it's showing this error.

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the
>   following errors must be resolved:

I've reinstalled `DotNetBar` but the error is not going away when I open that form - all other forms are working correctly without any error. I have tried rebuilding and cleaning the solution but the result is the same!

Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Try and Clean/Build your solution from the `Build` menu and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried deleting the .suo file? If not, close Visual Studio, THEN delete the .suo file (and also the bin and obj folders again while you're at it).

Comment: It's in the same folder as your ".sln" file.

Comment: .suo is not showing here its VS 2010 and C# is I am using. I deleted Bin an Obj folder but no change... :-(